# bash: setting tab field separator with variable

Tags: bash, unix, tabs, gnu-coreutils

Some bash tools such as sort, join, cut (all coreutils?) require field separator to be passed in a somewhat peculiar way for tabs: `sort -t $'\t' ...`. There are many questions here that address this behavior.

My problem is I am trying to pass the field separator as a variable, such as:

```
SEP="\t"
sort -t $SEP ...
```

With normal characters, that works, but not with tabs. I tried a few variations, but none of them work. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it using [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```
sep=$'\t'
```

And call it as `"$sep"`, quotes are important to preserve the literal meaning:

```
sort -t "$sep" file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt 
foo     bar
spam    egg
abc     def

$ sep=$'\t'

$ sort -t $sep file.txt 
sort: multi-character tab ‘file.txt’

$ sort -t "$sep" file.txt 
abc     def
foo     bar
spam    egg
```

Also note that, to get rid of the ambiguity with the environment variables i have used lowercase characters for the variable name, unless you have a very good reason you should do so too.

Comment: I thought I tried every combination, but somehow missed that one. Thank you for the prompt response!

Comment: @burger Glad i could help :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the keys [CONTROL]+[V] before pressing [TAB] to introduce the tab char.

```
echo "a b   c" |cut -d" " -f2
```

b

Be careful if you copy paste the code, as the tabs may be lost, as they are lost in fact, in this post :-)

Comment: Why downvoted without comments? It is valid to insert Tab in source code.